# How to respond to fetch event for a navigation in service worker?

Tags: javascript, service-worker

I have created a SPA (Single Page Application) with Create-React-App. I added a service worker to it so that the SPA could load when there is no network connection. The service worker successfully caches all the resources but fails respond when there is no network connection. I've tried many things but just couldn't get it to serve the assets to get offline capabilities. It gives the following error message:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to fetch

My service worker registers successfully and also caches assets successfully. Service Worker code:

```
const thingsToCache = [
  'index.html',
  'static/js/1.cb2fedf5.chunk.js',
  'static/js/main.5e7fdc75.chunk.js',
  'static/js/runtime~main.229c360f.js',
  'static/css/main.ca6d346b.chunk.css',
  'static/media/roboto.18d44f79.ttf',
  'static/media/comfortaa.7d0400b7.ttf',
];

this.addEventListener('install', event => {
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('v1').then(cache => {
      return cache.addAll(thingsToCache);
    })
  );
});

this.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  //respond to fetch requests here
  caches
    .match(event.request)
    .then(cachedRes => {
      if (cachedRes) {
        event.respondWith(cachedRes);
      } else {
        throw new Error('No match found in cache!');
      }
    })
    .catch(() => {
      return fetch(event.request);
    });
});
```

If you need the assets, then here's the link:

https://github.com/Twaha-Rahman/pwa-problem-assets

Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error in your `fetch` event listener. You need to call `event.respondWith` instead of `event.waitUntil` and it has to be at the top level. See below for a slighly amended version.

```
this.addEventListener('fetch', event => {
  event.respondWith(
    caches
      .match(event.request)
      .then(cachedRes => {
        if (cachedRes) {
          return cachedRes;
        } else {
          throw new Error('No match found in cache!');
        }
      })
      .catch(() => {
        return fetch(event.request);
      });
  )
});
```

More details: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API/Using_Service_Workers